# Do we have enough evidence to determine Qyburn's champion?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

spoilers:

> He spends the entire *A Feast for Crows* doing secret experiments on Gregor Clegane, there are hints that he has a history of necromancy, and he orders a suit of armour "too huge to be worn by any human"... That has to be a Frankenstein Gregor Clegane right?

so with TLP's help

> There is overwhelming evidence pointing to the Mountain, question is whose head does he have since the Dornishmen have the his head?

Comment: So you have not read ADWD?

Comment: Mayhaps you recall [Ser Robert Strong](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_Strong) of the Kingsguard, who carries Cersei off after she is forced to walk naked through the city?

Comment: Guy please care to mention the scope of the spoilers. Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering all that Qyburn has been up to, including the evidence that you present, the only logical choice is

> Gregor Clegane. Most likely in some sort of "Frankenstein" form since as you said, his head was sent to Dorne, and Qyburn would have extra parts from the other people he has been "experimenting" with.

Comment: Yes, this is why Robert Strong never takes off his helm and is "sworn to silence".

Answer (score 4):

We see further evidence that

> Ser Robert Strong

is the Mountain from very early on in the series during one of [Bran's dreams](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dreams_and_prophecies#Bran.E2.80.99s_Dreams):

> He saw his father pleading with the king, his face etched with grief. He saw Sansa crying herself to sleep at night, and he saw Arya watching in silence and holding her secrets hard in her heart. There were shadows all around them. One shadow was as dark as ash, with the terrible face of a hound. Another was armoured like the sun, golden and beautiful. Over them both loomed a giant in armour made of stone, but when he opened his visor, there was nothing inside but darkness and thick black blood.

The shadow with the face of a hound is clearly a reference to Sandor Clegane, the hound. It seems likely then that the giant here is Gregor. The stone armour is a reference to his nickname, the Mountain. The fact that his visor is empty foreshadows Gregor having his head cut off and sent to Dorne. Oberyn's poisons also caused Gregor's blood to turn black and thick.

It seems to me like the connections between the Mountain and this knight with an empty visor indicate that the Mountain is Ser Robert Strong. This also answers your second question, since it means that Ser Robert Strong has no head at all. I believe many of the character's mention that they never see him take off his helmet, or do other things such as use the privy, which kind of indicates that he isn't quite human.

Comment: I think people are reading too much into this vision. This was written early in AGOT. It clearly focuses on the present, like a snapsnot of what the Starks are doing right now. The giant is ambiguous, but in my opinion it makes no sense for it to be Ser Gregor, who is merely a henchman to Tywin. It would make more sense if it was Ser Ilyn Payne.

Comment: @TLP How does Ser Ilyn Payne loom over Sandor Clegane? It's obviously Gregor foreshadowing his head removal and poisoning.

Comment: Why would Gregor Clegane becoming Robert Stone be in a vision for Bran, when he is looking down on his family at Darry castle?

Comment: @TLP By that logic, why would the Hound be there? Or why would Jamie Lannister be there in his gold armour? Because Bran is a greenseer, that's why. He's seeing significant figures.

Comment: Because the Hound *was* there. That was the aftermath of the incident when Arya's wolf mauled Joffrey and she threw Lion's Paw in the river (the Trident), and the Hound killed Mycah -- the butcher's boy -- and Ned Stark killed Sansa's wolf Lady. Jaime was with them, and he was the one that had tried to kill Bran. This is very early in AGOT, page 163, and the scene begins with Bran seeing everyone in Westeros as a snapshot of what they are doing right now. People have speculated that the vision of Jon is a foreshadowing of his death, but that is also rather speculative, IMO.

Comment: @TheMathemagician I don't know where you are getting your information from, but Sansa was not happy at that point. The chapter before that is where Ned kills her wolf Lady. You should avoid making personal attacks, there is no need to get angry when discussing literature.

Answer (score 1):

I think he is reviving robb stark.
Qyburn is probably putting robb stark's head on the mountain's body.
Reference: 1.Robb stark saved him once.
2. Robb stark's corpse was headless with the direwolf's head sewn on it.
3. The mountain's head is in dorne.

Comment: and how would Robbs head get to Qyburn. I don't recall the Frey's sending the head to KL. And even if they did, there are a few weeks between the beheading of Robb and of Gregor, so Robbs head can't be much more than a skull at this time.

Comment: It would be a hell of an unexpected twist.